# Trigger Google Home using Python

Tags: automation, iot, google-home

I am trying to connect my Python script to my google home. Python script is not run locally, so a simple flask application to trigger the google home to play a song is not a solution. I’ll be running the Python script on a service which is hosted in a server (herokuapp etc). Is there any way to trigger my Google home in this case?

Example:
My Python script will be scraping weather data of a location, whenever it rains in a specific location, I need to play a song/sound in my google home.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Tried building a flask application, but it works only when the python script is run locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/device-registration/register-device-manual) for Google Assistant SDK for triggering your Google Home. Also, more information about how to run a python script on a service in a server can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview).

Comment: These links bring to pages stating "Conversational Actions were deprecated on June 13, 2023. "